# ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws.x2004.x09.policy.PolicyDocument$Factory

Tags: java, soap, classnotfoundexception

I am new to SOAP-UI. When I am trying to parse WSDL using **soapui-4.0.1.0.jar** it is throwing exception

> ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws.x2004.x09.policy.PolicyDocument$Factory

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Stack Trace: [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.policy.PolicyUtils.getAddressingPolicy(PolicyUtils.java:303), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.policy.PolicyUtils.getPolicy(PolicyUtils.java:287), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.policy.PolicyUtils.getAttachedPolicy(PolicyUtils.java:249), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.AbstractSoapBindingImporter.initWsAddressing(AbstractSoapBindingImporter.java:43), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.Soap12HttpBindingImporter.importBinding(Soap12HttpBindingImporter.java:88), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter.importBinding(WsdlImporter.java:264), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter.importWsdl(WsdlImporter.java:154), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter.importWsdl(WsdlImporter.java:80), com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter.importWsdl(WsdlImporter.java:75),

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and the code to which it points.

Comment: I have added stack trace with question.

Comment: Missing class "org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws.x2004.x09.policy.PolicyDocument$Factory" is avilable in "sca-upgrade.jar". i am unable to find that jar on the web.

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/sca-upgrade.jar.html?all=true

Answer (score 1):

I have tested/executed and able to parse WSDL's using policy-xmlbeans-1.5.jar and later commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar is also required.

OC4J jar referred on findjar didn't worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassNotFoundException` indicates that you may not have included the necessary dependencies/jars in your project.  The [`org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws.x2004.x09.policy.PolicyDocument`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html) class you seek may be found on the [OC4J](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/utilsoft-090603.html) page according to [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/xmlsoap/schemas/ws/x2004/x09/policy/PolicyDocument.html).

Comment: Yes exactly Mr. Nicholas, jar is missing but i am not able to find jar even at findjar.com. only classes are displayed there.

Comment: It is true that only classes are display on the findjar page but a zip containing the jar can be acquired from the [OC4J](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/utilsoft-090603.html) page.